# Correct network analysis settings needed for shortest route problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

Why does the route analysis take a longer path to reach the point when i click the solve button, even though I can see a shorter path with my naked eye?

I'm trying to digitize again and make a new network dataset, but it's still same like before.

Am I missing any steps during creating the network?

Comment: Your network has one or more small breaks along the apparent shorter paths.  It needs to be connected and cleaned before you can use it reliably for route analysis.

Comment: im using arcgis 9.3 right now ,, thank you for your attention ,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Network elements like roads must connect at either endpoints (ex: polyline splits) or a vertex on a polyline. You can use some tools like planarize to create these. You must set the connectivity for your sources to "endpoint" or "any vertex". Make sure to rebuild your network dataset afterwards.